# Integral $\int\frac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

integral of $\displaystyle \int \frac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}dx$

$$\int \frac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x} {\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x} dx$$

OR $\displaystyle \int \frac {\sin x \cos x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}$

Apologies for not mentioning the context of the question. It was some years ago. I was trying to solve an integration problem on an educational application. I was able to reduce the original question to the integral I had asked here. Now I don't remember the context. But I think I was able to provide a solution with the answers mentioned here. Thank you all and math.stackexchange.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Would you mind telling us the context of this question? I ask because sometimes definitely integrals with similar integrands come up in competitions and so if there are limits of integration then that could potentially make things easier.

Comment: I am familiar with Latex math script.  Perhaps MathJax is a little different script. Sorry if my question was not properly formatted.

Comment: [Integration of $\int\frac{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1657010) - found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%5E4%20x%20%2B%20%5Ccos%5E4%20x%7D%7B%5Csin%5E3%20x%20%2B%20%5Ccos%5E3%20x%7Ddx%24&p=1).

Comment: @kvnmurty, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very bad and low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos, Mr Angelo, Mr MartinSleziak, Mr user328442. I was able to provide a solution using your suggestions and tips. Thanks 

Answer (score 3):

Since it is your first question I will be nice this time. Next time, please learn how to write [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) code to make your math look better, and please show some effort or give some context. That will make your questions much better.

In both your integrals, let
$$
u=\cos x-\sin x.
$$
The first one will transform into
$$
\int\Bigl(\frac{2/3}{1+u^2}+\frac{1/3}{u^2-2}-1\Bigr)\,du
$$
while the second one will be
$$
\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^4-u^2-2}\,du.
$$
I'm sure you can take care of these.

Comment: I am familiar with Latex math script. Perhaps MathJax is a little different script. Sorry if my question was not properly formatted. 

Thanks for answering my query. It is nice of you.

Comment: Your solution is very useful. I will try it ..

Answer (score 2):

$$a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=(a+b)(a^n+b^n)-ab(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$$ implies $$\dfrac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}=(\sin x+\cos x)-\dfrac{\sin x  \cos x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}$$ and $$\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x=(\sin x+\cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x).$$ Therefore $$-\dfrac{\sin x  \cos x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}=\dfrac{1}{\sin x +\cos x}-\dfrac{1}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}.$$

Comment: I suspect this is why OP had two integrals in the question, they'd already figured out this equivalence.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for acknowledging my effort.

Comment: The last line  contains a 2nd term with 1 in the Nr, and sin^3 x + cos^3 x in Dr.  I don't recall an easy integration of this 2nd term. Please do not mind if I ask for a method to integrate that term.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @kvnmurty:My intention was to break your giant into manageable pieces, not to solve the problem. Here we have $$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x} dx=\displaystyle\int\left((\sin x+\cos x)+\frac{1}{(\sin x + \cos x)}-\frac{1}{(\sin x + \cos x)(1-\sin x\cos x)}\right) dx.$$

Comment: Thanks @Bumblebee. Appreciate your support

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dfrac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}=(\sin x+\cos x)-\dfrac{\sin x  \cos x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}$,  we only need to evaluate
$$
A:=\int \frac{\sin x \cos x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x} d x.
$$
First of all, we split the integrand into 2 parts.
$$
\frac{3 \sin x \cos x}{\sin ^{3} x+\cos ^{3} x}=-\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}+\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{1-\sin x \cos x}
$$
Then $$
3 A=-\underbrace{\int \frac{d x}{\sin x+\cos x}}_{J}+\underbrace{\int \frac{\cos x+\sin x}{1-\sin x \cos x} d x}_{K}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=\int \frac{d x}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{d x}{\cos \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\sec \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\tan \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|+c_{1} \\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sin x-\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right| +c_1\\
K &=2 \int \frac{d(\sin x-\cos x)}{(\sin x-\cos x)^{2}+1} \\
&=2 \tan ^{-1}(\sin x-\cos x)+c_{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$A= \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sin x-\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right|+ \frac{2}{3}  \tan ^{-1}(\sin x-\cos x) +C$$
Hence  $\boxed{\displaystyle \int \frac{\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x}{\sin^3 x + \cos^3 x}dx=\sin x-\cos x+ \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} \ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sin x-\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right|+ \frac{2}{3}  \tan ^{-1}(\sin x-\cos x) +C }$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Riemann.  And Lai.